# JSF Page Navigation+Data flow

Tags: jsf-2, dataflow

I am new to JSF and started learning and have worked on struts. Just wanted to understand how navigation works in JSF2.0. I understand in JSF2.0 navigation rules can be done in  `faces-config.xml`. But I would like to understand how it works in real world.

Suppose I have a screen to enter search criteria and the next screen should dispaly the search results.Where do I process the result set `<h:commandButton value="Show Results"
action="#{simpleController.doNavigation}"/>`and my doNavigation() does the job of querying the database and fetch the results, how do I carry it next screen. Do I need to hold the value in SESSION

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the data as a property of the current bean instance.

```
public String doNavigation() {
    results = searchService.find(query);
    return "nextpage";
}
```

By default, navigation doesn't fire a new request, it just sets the target page to the current response. In the target page, you can just use `#{simpleController.results}`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this is a poor practice (bad for SEO and UX). Rather show the results in the very same page and don't perform navigation on postbacks.

#### See also:

- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one/15523045#15523045)
- [Problems with navigation cases from an embedded JSF 2.0 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756533/problems-with-navigation-cases-from-an-embedded-jsf-2-0-application/10756821#10756821)